# how to run Deno on termux?

Tags: javascript, deno, termux

Is there any way to run deno on termux . I had searched on internet  but no help or there is no possibility till now to run on phone

Comment: I think the time has not come yet

Comment: What is preventing you from doing so?

Comment: u need deno compile, it won't work with js compiler allone.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I installed arch Linux on Termux and downloaded the latest release (deno src tar file) from deno's GitHub address and installed it with cargo build. The 8GB Termux reaches a size of about 17GB, but we can clean it after compiling.